# Problem with linking

Tags: qt, qt4

I made a custom library and i compiled it into a dll (qustom.dll).

Now i want to compile another project using this dll.

What i did is to import the header files in the project and add this line in my .pro file

```
LIBS += -lqustom
```

but i get "error: cannot find -lqustom"

also i tried

```
LIBS += qustom.dll
```

and

```
LIBS += -libqustom.a
```

qustom.dll is in the project directory

Also i tried

```
OTHER_FILES += \
    qextserialport1.dll
```

but didn't work either

Am i missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

Missing a path perhaps? `-L/path/to/dlls -ldllname`

Qt plays nicely with CMake. I use that and I never get dependency/path headaches like this any more.

Comment: I added this `LIBS += -L"c:/Users/vilus/Desktop/qqprjt/" -lqustom` and now i get `error: collect2: ld returned 1 exit status`

Comment: Does it say anything more specific than that?

Comment: Sorry, I need more clues. All I can say now is "give CMake a go." It really is that good.

Comment: Full error (preferably whole log) would tell most likely that your path is wrong or something... Hard to say anything definite without it though.

Comment: Oh and also, maybe QMake doesn’t know how to convert / into \, did you try with backslashes too?